# Laravel Route Params and Form Params

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a Backend in Laravel, which is basically a REST API, because I'm using AngularJS in the FronEnd and making ajax requests.

Let's say I have to make a simply CRUD for Users

And I don't know if there is any difference between putting some of the parameters in the Route itself or all of them in the Form Input.

For Example:

```
Route::post('/Users/Update', 'UsersController@update);
```

And then call the 'id' parameter from:

```
Input::get('id')
```

or

```
Route::post('/Users/Update/:id', 'UsersController@update);
```

and include it as a parameter of the function update like:

```
public function update($id) { }
```

Is there any real difference between this two ways? maybe security issues? coding standards? or is it the same?

Should I just use Laravel's REST controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a REST API you should have a URL like `example.com/posts/42` and not `example.com/posts?id=42` because it is cleaner and it is a coding standard.

I would also drop uppercase characters in your URLs and definitely go for your second choice of implementation. By the way, if you need to update a user you should use a PUT request like so: `PUT users/:id`.

Comment: I was just reading about PUT and DELETE, because I've heard before that there were insecure but I don't know they that was said.

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich Why would they be insecure? They are as secure as other HTTP methods. Take a look at Wikipedia to choose the right HTTP method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services

Comment: I was not sure, I red that some browsers do not support them

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich Under the hood Laravel handles PUT request in forms as POST when you are using a PUT method in a form.But if you are building an API, you'll likely call it from other servers / command line interface / mobile applications. And they handle perfectly this!

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich My source for the PUT method: http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form It starts at: `Since HTML forms only support POST...`

Comment: awesome! ty, this is not a problem anyway because all form submission go through AngularJS ng-submit and through XHR

Answer (score 0):

### The concise some-what opinionated answer:

You should define your route as:

```
Route::put('/users/:userId', 'UsersController@putUser');
```

Your `public function putUser($userId) {}` should return a `204 No Content` on success.

### The reasoning:

I've changed the route to be a `PUT` request to closer follow REST principles. Changing the controller method to `putUser` from `update` allows us to better define what the method is intending to do. While it seems trivial, it will help you distinguish between a `PUT` and `PATCH` update if you ever decide to implement one in the future. I used PUT as the method here but you can read about PATCH vs PUT and decide how far you want to go into following REST principles.

As for laravels restful controllers I feel they impose restrictions and add no real benefit so for REST api's I don't recommend using them.